# .htaccess Как убрать расширение .php и добавить слеш в конце?

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите где ошибка.

Реализовал удаление расширения `.php` но вот при добавлении `слеша` в конце происходит ошибка. Подскажите где ошибка, сам я пока что плохо знаком с `.htaccess`

вот `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

после чего пытался добавить слеш

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

все вместе не работает. мне кажется что я пытаюсь налепить все друг на друга и поэтому не работает, помогите разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему вы не экранировали символ слэша. Если вам надо просто отрезать расширение .php, лучше используйте этот код:

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ $1.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, пытался реализовать как вы написали, но когда открываю страницу меня переадресовывает на public_html/404.shtml/ и пишет что `Страница недоступна

Сайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.`

Comment: @harbor а какой адрес открываете?

Comment: @harbor и какой именно код использовали верхний или нижний?

Comment: @harbor а, сорри. перепутал части, сейчас нижний код должен работать правильно.

Comment: использовал верхний, работает только так `/user/redact.php/`

Comment: нижний не находит такой путь `Запрошенный URL / user / redact / не найден на этом сервере.`

Comment: @harbor попробуйте новую версию, должно работать правильно (и удалите из htaccess остальной код).

Comment: если у вас путь /user/redact.php, то надо использовать RewriteRule ^user/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ user/$1.php [L,R=301]

Comment: пробовал, все так же ситуация, не может найти url

Comment: или более универсальную версию RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ $1/$2.php [L,R=301]

Comment: спасибо за варианты, но все равно не работает, с `.htaccess` постоянные проблемы

Comment: так, попробуем не переадресацию, а просто rewrite RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ $1/$2.php [NC]

Comment: выполните этот код с другим флагом. что выдает? может влиять другой код в .htaccess, попробуйте его удалить перед выполнением запроса.

Comment: все, заработало, большое спасибо) не могу понять, столько разных вариантов реализации, но у каждого работает какая-то одна, почему так

Comment: там много нюансов. даже из-за неверного флага может не работать. совет на будущее - переносите всю обработку адреса в php, а там уже разбирайте с помощью регулярных выражений, а то при переходе на новую версию apache могу вылазить самые разные косяки.

Comment: да, спасибо, я пробовал делать обработку адреса через php, очень все удобно, но сделал много работы и все снова переделывать не закончив нельзя, так что когда все закончу и запущу, то можно будет поменять на обработку адреса через php

Comment: да, это можно реализовать со временем. раньше тоже обрабатывал через htaccess, но на более-менее крупном проекте его сложно использовать. появляется много дублирующего кода, когда сначала все идет на htaccess, а потом уже на php. плюс регулярные проблемы с совместимостью (особенно при переходе с apache 2.2 на apache 2.4, когда многие вещи кардинально поменялись).